# Create multivalued field for storing user skill set in user profile Django

Tags: django, django-models, autocomplete, many-to-many

I am building a user profile in django, where I want the user to enter his skill set. Any particular user can have multiple skills and there maybe many users which have a same particular skill.

So as far as I can get it from my limited understanding is that it is a ManyToMany field between the `userprofile` and `skills` but I want to allow the user to add as many skill as he/she wants to.

In addition to that I want to allow users to create new skills, if one does not exist in the current table. Along with that I want to plug in the autocomplete widget.

Any idea/ tips how I can do this? I can still do the autocomplete part, but unable to understand how I can add new skills, and link them to the user. It is quite similar to the `tagfield` on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Skill` model. The model represents a table in the database where every row in the table is a particular skill. Each skill is described by a `name` field. Then link it to your person with a `ManyToMany` field. You are then saying that 'each person can have zero or more skills'

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Person(models.Model):
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True, null=True)
```

If you are using the admin, a person/userprofile will now be able to select existing skills, or create new skills through the admin interface. If you are not using the admin interface there will be more steps involved that are outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, but I am not concerned only with admin interface and want to provide this facility to all users of website. Should I post that as a separate question?

Comment: Well, the above outlines the relationship between your objects i.e. the data model so you need to create the actual functionality. This is done by creating a `form` (or forms) to represent the data, a `view` to create and process these forms and a template to display it all to the user and allow them to submit. This is all the functionality that django's built-in admin takes care for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_skill(request, user_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
        skill_name = request.POST.get('skill_name')
    
        # Check if the skill already exists
        skill, created = Skill.objects.get_or_create(name=skill_name)
    
        user.skills.add(skill)
    
        return render(request, 'success.html')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).